# How do I Calculate the rotation corresponding to the following Unitary Matrix (Quantum Math)

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics

\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\pi }\cos\theta &-e^{-i\pi \:}\sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta \:&-\cos\theta \:\end{pmatrix}

Comment: note that $e^{i\pi}=-1$ and that $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is $2\pi$ periodic. The degree of rotation is just $\theta$

Comment: You'll need to specify which correspondence you're thinking of. We could put this matrix into correspondence with all sorts of rotation matrices. Also, note that you get proper formatting for functions like $\cos$ and $\sin$ by using commands like `\cos` and `\sin`. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\pi}\cos\theta&-e^{-i\pi}\sin\theta \\-\sin\theta&-\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\cos\theta &\sin\theta \\-\sin\theta &-\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}=(-1)\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &-\sin\theta \\\sin\theta&\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos (\theta +\pi)&-\sin (\theta+\pi)\\\sin (\theta+\pi)&\cos (\theta+\pi)\end{pmatrix}$.

This is a rotation by $\theta +\pi$.